# Get information about whereabouts of plotting output in R programmatically

Tags: r, plot

I have a function that returns a rather large object of a certain type (complicated list structure), 
which doesn't make sense to display to the user, because it clutters the screen.

```
returnsMuchStuff <- function() {
    ret <- list(x=rnorm(170), y=rnorm(170))
    class(ret) <- "MuchStuff"
    return(ret)
}
```

But I have a plotting function which can display the content in a plot. So I would like
to override the plotting functionality such that the plot is directly shown when the functions returns:

```
print.MuchStuff <- function(stuff) {plot(stuff$x, stuff$y)}
returnsMuchStuff() # displays plot - if plot can be displayed
```

This works fine if I use RStudio, for example.
But I would also like to support users on the command line using a terminal server, which can't directly view the plot.
In this case, It might be that the default output is a PDF file.

Then I would like to display a message "PDF file /path/to/file created with plot" because otherwise it is not obvious to a user what happens here.

Is it somehow possible to detect whether the user uses a graphical interface or whether the output will be plotted in a file?
And if it is plotted in a file, how can I get the path?

The only thing I found on this is to use `options("device")`. 
But this outputs a function, from which I cannot extract this information programmatically:

```
> options("device")
$device
function (file = if (onefile) "Rplots.pdf" else "Rplot%03d.pdf",
    width, height, onefile, family, title, fonts, version, paper,
    encoding, bg, fg, pointsize, pagecentre, colormodel, useDingbats,
    useKerning, fillOddEven, compress)
{
    initPSandPDFfonts()
    new <- list()
    ....
}
```